# Execute shell command in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, shell, command-prompt

I have a question regarding executing shell commands in c++. I'm building an application in winforms, vs 2008. My application has a button, when clicked should decode a binary file to a .csv file. I can decode files by first going to the right directory (cd Test_Copy2) and then execute a command in the command prompt (java -jar tool.jar -b x.fit x.csv). I tried a lot of different stuff but unfortunately got none to work!

I tried using:

```
system,  _popen,  ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe ", L"java -jar Tool.jar -b x.fit x.csv", L"C:\\Test_Copy2", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Can anyone please provide me with an example on how to do that? I dont know where I'm going wrong, most of the time the command prompt opens but no command is executed!

Comment: CreateProcess? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx

Comment: You should describe what errors you got when you tried all the different ways to launch the java app. Was the problem that the java.exe binary could not be found, was it that Java couldn't find your .jar file, or that your Java app couldn't find the data files?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run the jar in a cmd.exe instance, you need to add one of the correct command line switches to cmd.exe for it to work the way you want it to:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

For instance, your command string should be:

```
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c java -jar Tool.jar -b x.fit x.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I go to the right directory first? because my home directory is not the same as the files directory!

Comment: Use _chdir() to change the current working directory of your program.

Comment: Or try `C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c java -jar Tool.jar -b C:\\path\\to\\x.fit C:\\path\\to\\x.csv`. You should avoid `chdir` in programs; it's somewhat of a hidden global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `system()` function to execute shell commands.
For example:
`system("DIR")` executes the DIR command in the CMD shell. The  default directory at the start is the directory you're `.exe` file is located.
'system("PAUSE")` executes the PAUSE command.
The command/s you wannt to execute should be passed as a constant string to the function.

### Edit:

For you paritcular program the syntax (IMO) would be:

`system("java -jar Tool.jar -b x.fit x.csv")`