# C++ : Simultaneously calling more than one *.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I need to call a bunch of *.exe's such that I call a notepad file where all the full paths are stored of all *.exe's to be called, and using that notepad file (which can be edited) I want to create a parent exe which calls a list where path of all child *.exe's are present

ALSO,
I need to initiate a call to all *.exe's "together" NOT "one by one".  I want a simultaneous call to all exe's, not a sequential one.

Thanks in advance.

I know this much coding about system calls:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
char * command;
sprintf_s("d:\\....path..%d.\\..%d",n,ctr);
system(command);
```

Comment: Great! And what is question?

Comment: Execute a single script(batch/shell) from C++ which runs all the required exe.

Comment: @juergen d i want to do this task which i have defined above and i want the syntax to do it i am working on win 7 64 bit and c++ is the language

Comment: Don't mix C code into C++ applications. You really don't have to.

Comment: also, dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244439/execute-another-program-in-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672257/using-system-to-execute-a-command-in-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232304/execute-shell-command-in-c , and probably many more

Answer (score 1):

If you only target Windows, you can use the CreateProcess WinApi

(see an example usage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

On Unix like you will have to use fork()/exec() to achieve the same behavior

Comment: i need to call it recursively like a complete binary tree

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean by recusively ? Please enhance your question with a more concret example.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `sprint_s` (or other of the format string family) in C++.**

However: One of your errors is in the parameters to [`sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
int sprintf_s(
   char *buffer,
   size_t sizeOfBuffer,
   const char *format [,
      argument] ... 
);
```

Example by Microsoft:

```
// crt_sprintf_s.c
// This program uses sprintf_s to format various
// data and place them in the string named buffer.
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   char  buffer[200], s[] = "computer", c = 'l';
   int   i = 35, j;
   float fp = 1.7320534f;

   // Format and print various data: 
   j  = sprintf_s( buffer, 200,     "   String:    %s\n", s );
   j += sprintf_s( buffer + j, 200 - j, "   Character: %c\n", c );
   j += sprintf_s( buffer + j, 200 - j, "   Integer:   %d\n", i );
   j += sprintf_s( buffer + j, 200 - j, "   Real:      %f\n", fp );

   printf_s( "Output:\n%s\ncharacter count = %d\n", buffer, j );
}
```

Also note that this is a Microsoft extension. Compiling the same program with a different compiler might fail.

But seriously, don't use those at all, just do:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "d:/foobar.exe " << arg1 << ' ' << arg2;
const std::string command = ss.str();
```

On an even more serious note: Get a good introductory C++ book, and don't program C when you have C++ in your warehouse.